# Laravel:email is not going to non-domain addresses

Tags: laravel, email

I have following setting in .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.greenfintech.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=rizwan@greenfintech.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword    (Here I type password for rizwan@greenfintech.com)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Same settings are in config/mail.php file.

Code:

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $first_name = $request->fname;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    $data=compact('first_name','email','password');

    $sent = Mail::send('emails.sign-up-alert',$data,function($message) use($email)
    {
        $message->from('postmaster@mg.webmktgsolutions.com', "Parts-Search");
        $message->subject("Brake Project: Welcome to Parts Search");
        $message->to($email);

    });
    // dd(Mail::failures());
  }
```

I am sending emails from localhost (xampp). Emails are going fine when I am sending mails to rizwan@greenfintech.com, but mails are not going to razi.sagittarious@gmail.com/razi_sagittarious@yahoo.com..Do I need to set anything else or it's some other issue? Emails are going to only greenfin addresses but not going to gmail, yahoo, etc accounts.

Comment: checked your spam folder?

Comment: Also checked spam folder....no email there

Comment: Is there any method/technique to check errors of why email's is not going?

Comment: I don't really know what might be the issue here, some else might be able to help you :)

Comment: ok , thanks for your response

Comment: What script are you running to send the emails?

Comment: @Taylor Foster, I have updated question.

Comment: check your mail_host and port ,that  depend your hosting provider.

Comment: mail_host and port are fine..as mail is going to greenfin address, but don't now why it's not going to other mail accounts. Is that hosting provider issue?

Comment: make sure your host allows to send e-mails to non-domain addresses

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai, how would I know that? Actually it's company hosting , not mine.

Comment: I guess you are using cpanel hosting account, so try to contact your hosting provider to check the server logs for sent emails, your hosting provider will have access to check each sent mail from your hosting account and can get the reason why your emails were rejected by Gmail or Yahoo.

Comment: @dollar, ok thank you for your response.

Comment: try setting the "from" part to: rizwan@greenfintech.com and see if it gets delivered @Muhammad Rizwan

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai, $message->from('postmaster@mg.webmktgsolutions.com', "Parts-Search"); Here I changed postmaster@mg.webmktgsolutions.com to rizwan@greenfintech.com, but email is not going to gmail/yahoo email addresses.